# Add a line after the fragment in the LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to add a line after the man fragment in the LinearLayout to distinguish between the Map area and the yellow area below the map but the black line appear? How can I add a line after the map fragment?

I appreciate any helo.

**map.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00">

    <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#181407"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `android:orientation` to `vertical`. That will cause the `View` to appear below the fragment, not to the right of it.